# Splinter Headless Browser Not Initializing Within Airflow DAG

Tags: python, selenium, airflow, splinter

I'm setting up a web test using Splinter to run automatically every week with Airflow on a remote Ubuntu machine. When running in a python shell on the Ubuntu machine, the web test runs just fine (it's not that the test is failing) but when running within an Airflow PythonOperator, the web test fails when starting the Splinter browser.

I've cut out everything but the browser startup and the same error is occurring. I've found [some examples of using Selenium and Xvfb](https://github.com/airflow-plugins/Example-Airflow-DAGs/blob/6de30b12139f940521ffd6047e294c809d82acee/poc/selenium_example.py) but when I've implemented the same code to start and stop the virtual display, there's no change to the error message. I've tried removing paralellism by using concurrency limits on the DAG but the error persists. I've also checked the versions of my geckodriver and firefox and they seem ok (and they run when not run in the airflow)

This is the DAG:

```
def browser_test(queries, **context): 
    b = Browser("firefox", headless = True)
    b.visit('http://www.google.com')
    b.quit()

with DAG(
    dag_id = "web_test",
    start_date = datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval = None,
    concurrency=1,
    ) as dag: 

    PythonOperator(
    task_id = "run_pull", 
    python_callable = browser_test, 
    provide_context = True,
                            )
```

The error that is thrown is pretty big so I've cut it down to only the command issued and original exception ([full is here](https://pastebin.com/zECibP98));

```
joe@Ubuntu-VM1:~/airflow$ sudo airflow test web_test run_pull "2019-01-01"

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 660, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1542, in run
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 112, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 117, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/joe/ftp/files/Documents/Projects/Airflow/dags/dev_airflow.py", line 233, in browser_test
    b = Browser("firefox", headless = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 65, in __init__
    timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

And when just running python3 I'm able to import the DAG file and run the function browser_test without any errors.

I'd expect the DAG to run without any errors thrown and if I print the b.title() I'd expect it to be "Google". Honestly, I'd expect anything run within an Airflow DAG to react identically as when run in a Python shell?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a BashOperator to run the script? An example of using a BashOperator would be

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='web_test',
    bash_command='python web_test.run_pull()',
    dag=dag)
```

That could get around running Splinter directly within Airflow? It's not answering why you're having your problem but might fit your requirements?

Comment: run_pull is only one part of a longer DAG, It's the only part erroring so it's more than just getting it to run. I've just isolated it into the smallest code required to replicate. Saying that, if the bash operator is the only way to do it then that's how I'm going to have to do it. Still feels like a hack to be honest, why can't I just use the Python Operator and get Splinter running naturally?

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried using the bash operator and the same error occurs but this time within the bash operator output.